# AttributeError: EagerTensor object has no attribute 'astype'

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am trying to do a GradCAM Heatmap in Google Colab like so:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tf_keras_vis.activation_maximization import ActivationMaximization
from tf_keras_vis.utils.callbacks import Print

def model_modifier(m):
    m.layers[-1].activation = tf.keras.activations.linear

activation_maximization = ActivationMaximization(model, model_modifier)

loss = lambda x: K.mean(x[:, 1])

activation = activation_maximization(loss, callbacks=[Print(interval=100)])
image = activation[0].astype(np.uint8)         # <----- error

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5), subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []})
ax.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

but I get an error

```
AttributeError: EagerTensor object has no attribute 'astype'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to numpy first with `activation[0].numpy()`, then you should be able to use numpy array methods.

Answer (score 0):

While converting to a numpy ndarray and calling `astype()` certainly works, sometimes, it's desirable to keep using the tensor object. In that case, instead of `astype()`, one could use `tf.cast()`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
xx = tf.cast(x, tf.uint8)
print(xx)                   # tf.Tensor([1 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=uint8)
```